# why does "find" command not working in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the problem that the `find` command, given at command level, works as expected; but when the same command is executed from a script, it does not.

When I put this code at the prompt, it works:

```
find . -name *\20191202.bin -print
```

and the result is:

```
./IM/history_20191202.bin
./BAL/detail_20191202.bin
./REC/imbalance_20191202.bin
./DE/chart_20191202.bin
./FA/cases_20191202.bin
```

I can get the result as you can see .

But if I run the bash file containing the same command, it does not work:

```
#!/bin/bash
read number1
read number2

echo "HELLO SHELL"

START=$(date --date=$number1 +"%Y%m%d")
END=$(date --date=$number2 +"%Y%m%d")
CURRENT="$START"

#echo `date -d "$CURRENT 1 day" +"%Y%m%d"`

while [ "$CURRENT" != "$END" ]; do
    echo $CURRENT
    find . -name *\$CURRENT.bin -print
    #run shell job
    CURRENT=`date -d "$CURRENT 1 day" +"%Y%m%d"`
done
```

Above there is my shell script code. The logic  is,
first put the start year_month_date = ex. 20191010,
second put the last year_month_date = ex. 20191013, 
to find all files whose name includes 20191010, 20191011, 20191012.

But when I run the code I get the result:

```
HELLO SHELL
20191013
20191014
20191015
```

If someone knows how to get the correct result teach me please; the expected result is:

```
./IM/history_20191013.bin
./BAL/detail_20191013.bin
./REC/imbalance_20191013.bin
./DE/chart_20191013.bin
./FA/cases_20191013.bin
./IM/history_20191014.bin
./BAL/detail_20191014.bin
./REC/imbalance_20191014.bin
./DE/chart_20191014.bin
./FA/cases_20191014.bin
./IM/history_20191015.bin
./BAL/detail_20191015.bin
./REC/imbalance_20191015.bin
./DE/chart_20191015.bin
./FA/cases_20191015.bin
```

Comment: Don't escape the dollar-sign in the `find` command. Escaping that prevents the shell from expanding the variable, so it's looking for files with names literally containing a dollar sign, the word "CURRENT", and the extension ".bin". Also, that and a bunch of other variable references should be in double-quotes (i.e. `find . -name "*$CURRENT.bin" -print`) to prevent word-splitting and (premature) wildcard expansion. [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at spotting common mistakes like this. Finally, use lower- or mixed-case variable names.

Comment: Also, if you are in linux, why do you try to use backslash  as directory separator? It is wrong, and horrible!

Comment: find . -name "\*$CURRENT\*.bin" will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In script this command:

```
find . -name *\$CURRENT.bin -print
```

should be

```
find . -name "*${CURRENT}.bin" -print
```

to match names like `cases_20191015.bin`